# PrimeNG: CSS background for p-inputNumber

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG and find a way to set the background-color of a **p-inputNumber** control.

It is working fine with **pInputText**.

```
<!-- OK -->
<input pInputText type="text" style="background: red;"/>

<!-- Not OK -->
<p-inputNumber [showButtons]="true" style="background: red;"></p-inputNumber>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p-inputNumber` is a component rather than a simple input element and it style in different way base of the documentation page you can add a class for the internal input element by using the property `inputStyleClass`

add the css class in global style file

*style.css*

```css
input.bg-red{
 background:red;
 color:#fff;
}
```

*template*

```html
 <p-inputNumber inputStyleClass="bg-red" [(ngModel)]="value1"></p-inputNumber>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-cgngus?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 4):

I found the inline attribute too.

```
<p-inputNumber [showButtons]="true" [inputStyle]="{background: 'red'}"></p-inputNumber>
```